# Inconsistent overfull boxes and line breaks between systems

Tags: texlive

I have two systems, one running Debian and one running Ubuntu, and both have the latest version of TeX Live installed (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian and TeX Live 2019) from their respective repositories.  A paper I'm submitting is compiling significantly differently between these two systems, with inconsistent line breaks and overfull boxes.

Just by visual inspection Ubuntu is placing significantly more space following commas.  For example, in the following example document Ubuntu produces an overfull box while the line easily fits on Debian (with even enough room left over for the equation tag).

```
\documentclass[comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Since the output is not consistent between these systems, at least one must be in error, correct?  How do I tell which has the bug?  The date given on the log file is more recent on Ubuntu, but that log also says it's using the L3 programming layer so how do I know if it's a bug with that or not?  I've checked that it's not a problem with the document class as I'm using the same IEEEtran.cls on both systems.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: With the `comsoc` option, the `IEEEtran` tries to use  a Times compatible math font (cf. [How to Use the IEEEtran LaTeX Class](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf#page=2)). In your log, did you notice the messages `** Times compatible math font not found, forcing.` then
`-- Found newtxmath, loading.`?

Comment: So if you install a Times font on all your systems and use the `comsoc' option of IEEEtran, you might obtain the same results on all systems.

Comment: I do see that message, but even if I manually include the newtxmath package (the same version on both systems) I get different output.

Comment: @cbright See my updated answer if you can just install the missing fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked which fonts are used at both systems (used `pdffonts filename.pdf` on a Linux command line to see the fonts included/used by the files)? I would guess they are different and that is causing the differences.

**Edit:** As long as you do not explicitly define the font you want to be used within you document, you will see the "phenomenon" you described. But defining a font yourself is for sure, something the journal doesn't want to see.

**Edit:** You can try to install the standard MS True Type fonts on your Linux system. Search for the package "ttf-mscore" or "ttf_mscorefonts-installer". Besides Arial, Georgia and so one, you also get "Times New Roman". After installation, you might need to update the LaTeX font database in order to let LaTeX know about the new fonts.

Comment: You're right!  Ubuntu has EIBNFL+NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal and SDGCFO+rtxmi while Debian has FAMERT+NewTXMI.  But this is rather confusing---which output should I trust as 'canonical'?

Comment: They are both "true" and the version generated by the journal will (most probably) different again when they compile it on their Windows system.

Comment: That's quite annoying as I thought the whole point of a journal providing you with a document class is so that the output you compile will match the output on their end... but thanks for the help.

Comment: @cbright ignore the uppercase part before the + as that is a randomly generated string to give a unique name to the subset used in the document. So one installation is using  Nimbus Roman, which is the Ghostscript Times Roman clone font, which is typically what you get if you use `Times` the other is using NewTXMI which is the math italic font  from newtxmath, which matches the first comment under your question. If Times is not found it will use newtxmath.